# How to use CREATE TABLE queries in LibreOffice Base?

Tags: ubuntu, sql, libreoffice-base

I'm using LibreOffice 3.5.4.2 (from Ubuntu 12.04 packages) and trying to create tables using SQL's `CREATE TABLE` statement. For the first few attempts I got a message saying that the query must be a `SELECT` query. I changed the query and made it extremely simple:

```
CREATE TABLE moo3 (id_1 INT, name_1 VARCHAR(255));
```

Now the query seems to be executed, returning no results, but I can't find the table in Base's GUI. Is it a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to View/Refresh Tables to see the change. If you want to keep the lower case field names, you need to quote the them (at least in the embedded database SQL tool). And I realize that this is just a test, but you need to have a primary key field defined in order to enter data from the GUI. You could get data into the table other ways.